# SQL Set multiple column as primary key or declare them as unique (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table schema say `my_table` and i can create a primary key constraints using 5 of its columns, say `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`, they identify uniquely each row of my table, and they can't be null. Anyway, I'm only interested in making queries using column `A` and column `B`. So my questions are:

1. I create a Primary Key constraint using `(A, B, C, D, E)` and i create an index for the column `B` in order to query fast using that column (i'm not sure if an index on `A` is needed, due to `A` is the first col in the primary key, so it's supposed to be easy access)
2. I create a `uuid` as Primary Key and I declare a unique constraint on `(A, B, C, D, E)` and then i create an index for `A` and another for `B`.

I need to declare `(A, B, C, D, E)` as unique (either using a pk or unique constraints) because there are other tables using those columns as Foreign key.

So, I don't know if declaring a lot of column as PK is efficient, that's why i prefer option 2. Which option would you recommend? Pay attention on efficiency and/or possible costs.

Answer (score -1):

Create index(es) isn't free. Every time a tuple is inserted/updated has a cost, plus disk space.

Rule of dumb try to create the less indexes that you need.

Option 2, you're creating an unique index on A,B,C,D,E also adding a column and another index on it, seems to be a bad choice.

Option 1, if you're not sure A it's needed as a filter criteria and B yes, just create pk on (B,A,C,D,E) or whatever that meet your needs.
Then run your querys and look at the query plans with EXPLAIN. Finally create the necessary index to boost performance.

Greetings, Alejandro